# DRY principle in Python __init__ method

Tags: python, dry

In this class definition, every parameter occurs three times, which seems to violate the DRY (don't repeat yourself) principle:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, a=1, b=2.0, c=(3, 4, 5)):
        self.a = int(a)
        self.b = float(b)
        self.c = list(c)
```

DRY could be applied like this (Python 3):

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        defaults = dict(a=1, b=2.0, c=[3, 4, 5])
        for k, v in defaults.items():
            setattr(self, k, type(v)(kwargs[k]) if k in kwargs else v)
        # ...detect illegal keywords here...
```

However, this breaks IDE autocomplete (tried Spyder and Elpy) and pylint will complain if I try to access the attributes later on.

Is there a clean way to handle this?

Edit: The example has three parameters, but I find myself dealing with this when there are 15 parameters, where I only rarely need to override the defaults; often with more complicated types, where I would need to do

```
if not isinstance(kwargs['x'], SomeClass):
    raise TypeError('x: must be SomeClass')
self.x = kwargs['x']
```

for each of them. Moreover, I can't use mutables as default values for keyword arguments.

Comment: Don't overthink it. You don't have to drain your code of *all* moisture. The default way to do it is perfectly fine.

Comment: This is taking DRY too far. In one of the podcasts I have been listening to (of which I forgot the exact program), it was mentioned that in software engineering, many of the rules are more like guidelines than actual rules (which probably explains one of the reasons why many engineers look down upon software engineers).

Comment: Also, I have a feeling that this would be a better fit over at Software Engineering SE.

Comment: One such guideline is: make it as simple as possible, but no simpler. You've passed the point of simplicity here and are introducing unnecessary complexity. Not to mention that you're breaking Python's default args/kwargs behaviour.

Comment: In relation with what @deceze has said, do not forget the KISS principle, which you have violated, which is simply, "Keep It Simple, Stupid.".

Comment: I believe your first snippet has nothing to do with DRY. Your second snippet is sacrificing readability to solve a problem that wasn't there to begin with.

Comment: @deceze What am i breaking exactly?

Comment: You aren't repeating yourself; you are 1) setting default values for each parameter, 2) applying transformations to the arguments (though possibly unnecessarily), and 3) assigning values to instance attributes.

Comment: You don’t accept positional arguments anymore.

Answer (score 2):

As a preface, your code

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, a=1, b=2.0, c=(3, 4, 5)):
        self.a = int(a)
        self.b = float(b)
        self.c = list(c)
```

is, as mentioned in several comments, fine as it is. Code is read far more than it is written, and aside from needing to be careful to avoid typos in the names when first defining this, the intent is perfectly clear. (Though see the end of the answer regarding the default value of `c`.)

---

If you are using Python 3.7, you can use a data class to reduce the number of references you make to each variable.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import List

@dataclass
class Foo:
    a: int = 1
    b: float = 2.0
    c: List[int] = field(default_factory=lambda: [3,4,5])
```

This doesn't prevent you from violating the type hints (`Foo("1")` will happily set `a = "1"` instead of `a = 1` or raising an error), but it's typically the responsibility of the caller to provide arguments of the correct type.) If you really want to enforce this at run-time, you can add a `__post_init__` method:

```
def __post_init__(self):
    self.a = int(self.a)
    self.b = float(self.b)
    self.c = list(self.c)
```

But if you do that, you may as well go back to your original hand-coded `__init__` method.

---

As an aside, the standard idiom for mutable default arguments is

```
def __init__(self, a=1, b=2.0, c=None):
    ...
    if c is None:
        c = [3, 4, 5]
```

Your approach has two problem:

1. It requires that `list` be run for every instantiation, rather than letting the compiler hard-code `[3,4,5]`.
2. If you were type-hinting the arguments to `__init__`, your default value doesn't match the intended type. You'd have to write something like

   def **init**(a: int = 1, b: float = 2.0, c : Union[List[Int], Tuple[Int,Int,Int]] = (3,4,5))

A default value of `None` automatically causes a "promotion" of the type to a corresponding optional type. The following are equivalent:

```
def __init__(a: int = 1, b: float = 2.0, c : List[Int] = None):
def __init__(a: int = 1, b: float = 2.0, c : Optional[List[Int]] = None):
```

Answer (score 2):

Principles like DRY are important, but it's important to keep in mind the rationale for such a principle before blindly applying it -- arguably the biggest advantage of DRY code is that you increase the maintainability of the code by only having to modify it in one place and not having to risk the subtle bugs that can occur with code that is modified in one place and not another. DRY can be antithetical to other common principles like YAGNI and KISS, and choosing the correct balance for your application is important.

In particular, DRY often applies to default values, application logic, and other things that could cause bugs if changed in one place and not another. IMO variable names don't fit in the same way since refactoring the code to change every occurrence of `Foo`'s instance variable of `a` won't actually break anything by not changing the name in the initializer as well.

With that in mind, we have a simple test for your code. Are these variables likely to change together, or is the initializer for Foo a layer of abstraction that allows a refactoring of the inputs independently of the class's instance variables?

**Change Together:** I rather like @chepner's answer, and I'd take it one step further. If your class is anything more than a data transfer object you can use @chepner's solution as a way to logically group related pieces of data (which admittedly could be unnecessary in your situation, and without some context it's difficult to choose an optimal way to introduce such an idea), e.g.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass
class MyData:
    a: int
    b: float
    c: list

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, my_data):
        self.wrapped = my_data
```

**Change Separately:** Then just leave it alone, or KISS as they say.

Comment: To paraphrase: *business logic DRY* vs. *code DRY*. The former being many times more important than the latter.